# Como atualizar o backgroundWorker.ReportProgress() através de uma classe em outro projeto?

Tags: c#, winforms

Faço a leitura de um arquivo texto que contém dados de um outro banco de dados, carrego esses dados linha por linha para uma classe, edito os campos necessários e depois o salvo no novo banco de dados.

Esse processamento de inserção segue o seguinte padrão:

No `View`, seleciono o arquivo de texto e o passo por parâmetro para o `Controller`, que por sua vez chama o `Model`, que faz todo o processamento e chama o `AcessoADados` para salvar no banco de dados.

No `Form` da `View`, tenho um `BackGroundWorker`, onde o evento `Do_Work` chama o `Controller` para iniciar o processo.

Tenho também uma `progressBar`, que atualiza seus valores atraves do    `backgroundWorker.ReportProgress()` para informar a quantas anda o carregamento.

**Minha dúvida é:**

Como informar o `BackGroundWorker` que o progresso esta aumentando, a cada registro inserido, lá da classe `Model`?

Comment: Pessoal, até o momento nenhuma resposta funcionou. Quando o *BackGroundWorker* e o *processamento das informações* se encontram na mesma classe, eu consigo fazer. O problema é quando o processamento e a *BackGroundWorker* estao em Classes de *Projetos* diferentes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A estratégia que eu usaria seria passar um delegate que serve para notificar o progresso, que será chamado pela outra thread sempre que houver progresso, e então dentro desse delegate, atualizaria o form.

Assim sendo, o seu método de salvamento não fica dependente de elementos da interface, mas sim de um delegate que pode notificar o progresso para qualquer que seja o sistema de UI.

**Nota**

Em se tratande de Windows Forms, você terá de verificar dentro do código do delegate de notificação de progresso, a propriedade `InvokeRequired` do seu `Form`, de forma a saber se é necessário usar o método `Invoke` para poder fazer alteraões na interface de usuário.

Answer (score 1):

É simples, você tem que passar o método reportProgress como parâmetro

```
class FormView
{
    private void Something_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) 
    {
        new ModelClass().Insert((sender as BackgroundWorker).ReportProgress);
    }   
}

class ModelClass
{
    public void Insert(Action<int> reportProgress)
    {
    }
}
```